# Executing code in a python module as soon as it is included

Tags: python, import

I am attempting to use a module called interface.py which defines a list of conditions and a few functions to check arguments against those conditions. There are many thousands of conditions however, and so I want to use a dictionary instead of a list to prevent needing to look at all of them. To do this I'm using the following code:

```
def listToDictionary(list):
    """This function takes a list of conditions and converts it to a dictionary
    that uses the name of the condition as a key."""

    d = {}
    for condition in list:
        if condition.name.lower() not in d:
            d[condition.name.lower()] = []
        d[condition.name.lower()].append(condition)
    return d

conditionList = listToDictionary(conditions.list) #the condition list comes from another module
```

Further into the file are the actual interface functions that take arguments to compare with the list of conditions - these functions are written assuming that conditionList will be a dictionary.

Unfortunately this isn't working. Giving error details is difficult because this code is being imported by a django page and I am trying to avoid talking about django so this question stays uncomplicated. Essentially the pages including this code will not load, and if I change it back to just using a list everything works fine.

My suspicion is that the problem has to do with how Python treats import statements. I need the listToDictionary conversion to run as soon as interface.py is imported, otherwise the interface functions will expect a dictionary and get a list instead. Is there any way to ensure that this is happening?

Comment: Python executes the body of a module on import, so that's not your problem.

Comment: Naming a variable `list` is never a good idea, you'll be shadowing the built-in type. Use a different name instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I would even say: Naming a variable  `list` is always a terrible idea

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Changing it didn't solve the problem, but I always appreciate advice on coding practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An educated guess: the list in `conditions.list` is not yet fully constructed when your module is being imported. As a result, you get a dictionary that is missing some entries or even empty, which is causing problems later. Try deferring the construction of the dict, like this:

```
conditionTable = None     # shouldn't call it list if it's a dict

def get_cond_table():
    global conditionTable
    if conditionTable is None:
        conditionTable = listToDictionary(conditions.list)
    return conditionTable
```

Instead of referring to `conditionList` in your functions, refer to `get_cond_table()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately I still get the same problem. I'm starting to think the problem might be on the Django end, in which case attempting to simplify the problem might be shooting myself in the foot.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I found out that the problem was in another function that was still expecting the dictionary to be a list. The reason I couldn't see it right away is that Django left a very cryptic error message. I was able to get a better one using `python manage.py shell` and importing the module manually.

Thanks for your help everyone.